# Beamerposter example does not work

Tags: beamerposter

I want to create a poster using `beamerposter`. I am trying to compile [this example](http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/download/example-style-I6dv.pdf) from the package documentation.

Without touching anything, when I compile the `example-style-I6dv.tex`, I obtain 75 errors. I have `beamerposter.sty` and `beamerthemeI6dv.sty` in the project directory, so I don't understand why this example is not compiling smoothly.

Sample of errors that come up from the `beamerposter.sty`:

```
./beamerposter.sty:0: You have requested, on input line 42, version`2006/11/18' of package xkeyval,but only version`2005/01/30 v2.0 package option processing (HA)'is available.
./beamerposter.sty:128:Undefined control sequence. \ExecuteOptionsX{size=a0,scale=1.0}
./beamerposter.sty:128:Missing \begin{document}. \ExecuteOptionsX{size=a0,scale=1.0}
./beamerposter.sty:128:Undefined control sequence. \ExecuteOptionsX{size=a0,scale=1.0}
./beamerposter.sty:128:Undefined control sequence. \ExecuteOptionsX{size=a0,scale=1.0}
./beamerposter.sty:128:Undefined control sequence. \ExecuteOptionsX{size=a0,scale=1.0}
./beamerposter.sty:128:Undefined control sequence. \ExecuteOptionsX{size=a0,scale=1.0}
./beamerposter.sty:128:Undefined control sequence. \ExecuteOptionsX{size=a0,scale=1.0}
./beamerposter.sty:128:Missing number, treated as zero. \ExecuteOptionsX{size=a0,scale=1.0}
./beamerposter.sty:128:Undefined control sequence. \ExecuteOptionsX{size=a0,scale=1.0}
./beamerposter.sty:128: the input \ was incorrect and was ignored. on input line 128. the input \ was incorrect and was ignored.
./beamerposter.sty:129:Undefined control sequence. \ProcessOptionsX\relax
./beamerposter.sty:129:Undefined control sequence. \ProcessOptionsX\relax
./beamerposter.sty:129:Undefined control sequence. \ProcessOptionsX\relax
./beamerposter.sty:129:Undefined control sequence. \ProcessOptionsX\relax
./beamerposter.sty:129:Undefined control sequence. \ProcessOptionsX\relax
./beamerposter.sty:129:Undefined control sequence. \ProcessOptionsX\relax
./beamerposter.sty:129:Missing number, treated as zero. \ProcessOptionsX\relax
./beamerposter.sty:129:Undefined control sequence. \ProcessOptionsX\relax
```

What to do?

Comment: Why did I get down voted? Is my question not clear? How can I make my question better then?

Comment: Give a MWE! No one can help with the information given. Call \listfiles before \documentclass and give output. Not that _I_ can help but if you do that, maybe someone else can.

Comment: As per the first error message you posted, the `xkeyval` package you are using is too old. You may find that you need to update more than just that one package. You did not mention what distribution you are using. Take at look at [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/17427).

Comment: The `xkeyval` package has developed quite a bit over the years, and your other errors look related to keyval processing, so as @cyberSingularity this is almost certainly the issue. We'd need to see more of the log to say where `xkeyval` is being loaded from: you may have an old 'local' version somewhere.

Comment: @cyberSingularity - I am on it - stay tune!

Comment: Yes, that was it. It is now working fine. Thank you both, I learned something very useful!

Comment: Glad you sorted it. I think the normal procedure with issues caused a local installation setup is to close the question as too localised. This way it won't show up in the unanswered questions list any longer. @JosephWright may be able to help with this.

Comment: This question could help me, the future visitor, if it was not closed..